# Configure WSO2 developer studio 3.8.0 in eclipse Luna

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

[image]I am trying to configure WSO2 API Manager tooling in eclipse luna, as per https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/Learn/APIGateway/MessageMediation/pass-a-custom-authorization-token-to-the-backend/, however I keep getting javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException when I try to connect to API manager instance. I have added the public certificate in the java trust store, also tried pointing eclipse to custom truststore where the public cert is added, still no luck. I have java 8 installed on Mojave. Not sure, if it is related to new version of the API manager. Here is the error message and stack trace.

Error Message

```
Getting WS Feature Available in Regisrty check failed Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

https://pastebin.com/5bSpKJ4x `Stack trace link`

Answer (score 0):

This is a ssl Handshake error, which usually occurs if you don't have trusted certificates in your trust store. Do the following
Download the certificate from what ever back-end service you are trying to hit.
Add it to the client-truststore.jks file in < apim-home >/repository/resources/security using the following command in cmd.
 Open cmd from \jdk\bin 
keytool -keystore "< apim-home >\repository\resources\security\client-truststore.jks" -storepass wso2carbon -importcert -file "< certFile-loction >"

Comment: I am not getting this error while accessing any back-end service. I am getting this error when I am trying to configure publisher manager in WSO2 developer tool. Please find the screenshot I have attached in my original post.